# jquery-mobile formatting of collapsible elements

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm trying to make a multilevel sort of menu for a side panel. The code I'm using is in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sQRDm/2/). It sort of works but the content of the collapsible element is wrongly formatted, with the content of the list being cut out at both sides (tried in Firefox or Google Chrome). What is the correct way to do this? I don't like the  `data-inset="true"` option since it changes the entire appearance. I just want it to be whole wide but with the correct padding.
On the other hand, if there is another way to do it (like collapsible sets with elements that can't be expanded) I'm open to suggestions.

Disclaimer: I'm a total noob to jqm and web development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/m6zVq/

This css will fix your problem and it will not interfere with other listviews:

```
.ui-collapsible div ul {
    margin: -0.6em 0 !important; //counter top/bottom margins without changing default ones
}

.ui-collapsible div ul .ui-corner-top, .ui-collapsible div ul .ui-corner-bottom {
    border-radius: 0; // remove border radius
} 

.ui-collapsible div ul li.ui-li-divider {
    padding: 0.5em 15px 0.5em 12px !important;
}
```

**EDIT :**

Here's another solution: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/BfGJY/

Without css. But still a workaround. There's one listview above collapsible element and one listview below it.

## More info

If you want to learn how to do this kind of changes by yourself you should check this **[article](http://www.gajotres.net/learn-how-to-customize-jquery-mobile-application/)**, it will teach you how to do this by yourself.

Comment: Yes that seems to work, there is still a small border which I can remove with `.ui-collapsible-content  {border-left: 0px;border-right: 0px;}`. However, after looking at it, it does seem like the "Section 2" and the icon are not aligned with the list view title and icon and there is a border missing in the title header. Is there a better way to do this or do I have to fiddle with the CSS?

Comment: If you think about it everything here is set with css and you are creating a custom component. Problem here is a data-inset="false" which is not working correctly for listview inside a collapsible element. I have added a 3rd css block, it will solve your alignment. Play with it if you want better result.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The 3rd block let's me play with the "subsection" headers but not with the "Section" header which is what is actually misaligned. Anyway I'm marking your answer as correct. Again thanks.